# How do i create a URL in a list from 2 other fields

Tags: 2010, list

I have 2 columns in a list that I want to use to create a single URL by concatenating both values.

i.e. column1 value is 'www.bbc.co.uk', and column2 value is 'news'.

I want column3 to be a hyperlink to 'www.bbc.co.uk/news'

Thanks in advance
Colin

Answer (score 1):

A calculated column `=concatenate([column 1], "/", [column 2])` should do it.

Comment: Thanks very much - I had tried your suggestion previously but failed, I realised my error was column1 was a Hyperlink type - once I changed this to Single line of text, it worked.   Many thanks again.